# Mulesoft FTP Connector - File timestamps look incorrect

Tags: ftp, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

We are using mule-ftp-connector version 1.8.2. When Listing a dir with the List component the typedAttributes["timestamp"] value looks off.

E.g

File on ftp server has a datetime of 06/02/2023 08:26:52 this is shown in filezilla ftp client and also using command line ftp.

[image]

The typedAttributes["timestamp"] is showing 2002-06-23T08:26:52

[image]

Does anyone know what is going on here, I feel like I am missing something here.

The same question is asked in mulesoft forum: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00006WZU6uSAH/ftp-connector-file-timestamps-look-incorrect

Comment: I don't see this issue on my end when having a local FTP server running and using the FTP connector.Are the FTP server and your local machine based in different timezones? Do you see this issue with any other FTP server?

Comment: I get the correct timestamp if I use SMB connector, and also with other FTP clients such as FileZilla. 
I have not yet tried to check this with other FTP servers.

Comment: Can you add software details including the version number for the FTP server you're connecting to? This is probably a bug in the connector and that information will help.  The code is at https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-ftp-connector if that helps debug.

Comment: These are the mule application version details, I couldn't get FTP version info due to access issues. 

Anypoint Studio 7.11.0.202109282132 
Mule Server Runtime 4.4.0 EE 7.11.0.202212161259
MuleSoft Inc. Studio Core Libraries 7.15.0.202304280243